# Reuse look-behind character in regex for multiple consecutive substitutions

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have a string like this:

> `url.com/my?a=hello&b=world&z=foo`

I need to remove the `a` and `b` parameters, but not `z`. So I am using the following regex which mostly works:

> `s#((?<=\?)|(&))(a|b)=\w*(?(2)((?=&)|$)|(&|$))##g`

Basically it checks that `a` or `b` are prepended by `?` (look-behind) or `&`, and it must end with `&` or be the end of string. If it matched `&` at the beginning, it may match `&` at the end but doesn't consume it.

The problem I have is that it matches for `a` but not for `b` if they are consecutive, so it results in:

> `url.com/my?b=world&z=foo`

I guess after matching `a` the position is past the previous match so it starts looking at `b=...` without seeing again the look-behind character `?`, how can I make it search again including the non-consumed characters or should I separate the substitutions and search all the string independently?

Comment: Since this is a URI, why don't you use a URI parsing/building library instead of regexes?

Comment: You are right URI works best for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );

my $uri = 'http://url.com/my?a=hello&b=world&z=foo';

$uri = URI->new($uri);
$uri->query_param_delete($_) for qw( a b );

print "$uri\n";   # http://url.com/my?z=foo
```

Comment: Switched to solution that maintains param order.

Comment: ... and multiples of a parameter, and uri-encoded parameter names. You're welcome.